# Installing library on ubuntu

Tags: software-installation

I'm trying to install a gnuradio package , but when i run make command it gives an missing library , it's pcap so how can i install this lib ..

Error

```
/home/mohamed/OP25/op25/op25/gr-op25/lib/pcap_source_b_impl.cc:31:23: fatal error: pcap/pcap.h: No such file or directory
 #include <pcap/pcap.h>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a dependency. I suggest you do:

```
sudo apt-get install libpcap0.8-dev
```

Then try again.